# How to change div content if session[:user_id] = nil in rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this piece of code I use to display an element on my page if the user is logged in :

```
<% if session[:user_id] %>
<%= render partial: '/shared/admin_toolbox' %>
<% end %>
```

I think I could use that session[:user_id] to change the elements inside a DIV / SPAN if a user is logged out or in, however I don't know how.

For example : if the user is logged out I want the div to have the following code in it :

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Log In</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Register</a>
```

... and if the user is logged in I want it to have

```
<p>Hello, (USER) !</p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Log Out</a>
```

I know how to show the text if the user is logged in, but I have no idea how to change the stuff in the div. Help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `else` in your condition. In ruby, `nil` is considred `false`. If we assume that `session[:user_id]` is nil when the user is logged in, it's easy to generate the corresponding logic:

```
<% if session[:user_id] %>
  <%= "I'm logged in so do something inside this block" %>
<% else %>
  <% "I'm logged out and will execute this block if session[:user_id] is nil" %>
<% end %>
```